# Ошибка плагина Workhard, Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/a/arsenikr/o-beru.ru/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2162

Установлен плагин WorkHard и я не могу войти в пункт меню "настройка доступа к определенным папкам", выдает ошибку, которую написал выше. Дело в том, что я всего лишь редактор и немного разбираюсь в верстке, абсолютно не шаря в цмс-ке, серверах и т.д. Погуглив, я узнал, что проблему можно решить повысив лимит памяти, изменив значения в файле wp-config.php в строках define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M'); define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' ); как мне туда попасть и могу ли я вообще это сделать? спасибо

Comment: Обратить к автору этой никому неизвестной поделки (плагина).

Comment: пробовал, он морозиться, какие-то базовые советы из гугла дает